# Thin Guava Plant. Too late to 'top'?

Tags: planting

I have guava plant from seed that is about 14 months old. It is about 50 centimetres tall, lots of leaves on top but it is VERY thin, about 5mm (millimetres).
Shall I let it grow or top it? From reading other questions I now realise I should have topped it a long time ago.
Help!

Comment: What is your goal by topping the plant? Guavas want to be a tree so topping only delays that

Comment: I am just worried it's going to become to tall & thin to carry the leaves. The trunk is very thin as mentioned above  currently I have 4 thin bamboo sticks surrounding the plant to support it.